# iPhone scroll view / dynamic text in label then table view and images

Tags: iphone

what is the right way to place table view after label that populated dynamical and cannot guess what its height and they are all placed in scroll view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableView has a header title.. so why don't you just use a table view instead of a scroll view and set it's header title dynamically?

Comment: Thanks for the reply
but what if there is a photo after the table , or even i need to place another table view ?